# mongod.exe service memory keeps increasing , but not decrease

Tags: mongodb, out-of-memory, mongodb-.net-driver

We have implement Mongo Database with C# driver in asp.net application. We are facing the memory issue. The mondod.exe service keeps increase but not decrease, and automatic connection accepted and end connection.

The below mentioned code we have implemented for the mongo db connection:

```
internal static MongoDatabase GetDatabase()
{
 string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoDBConnString"].ConnectionString;
 string databaseName = MongoUrl.Create(con).DatabaseName;

 MongoClient client = new MongoClient(con);
 MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
 MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase(databaseName);

 if (server != null)
  if (server.State == MongoServerState.Connected)
   server.Disconnect();
 return db;
}
```

Please suggest how to decrease the mondod.wxe service memory. and best practice for implementation.

Comment: You say that your server is consuming RAM, it is expected, to be fast MongoDB tries to put data in RAM and keep it. This is based on the storage engine that use Memory Map File : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/ - So do you have a concrete issue? (crash? db being slower?, ...)

Comment: when consuming RAM, the application crash.

Comment: You are talking about the "client" (developed in C#) not the server right?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal and nothing to worry about. MongoDB grabs as much memory as it can to cache as much of your data as possible. However, MongoDB only grabs memory which is not required by other processes. So when another process needs more memory, the memory held by MongoDB will be released.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running any edition of Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7, please install a hotfix to resolve an issue with memory mapped files on Windows.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2731284